# Scheme if structure

Tags: if-statement, scheme

It gives me this error for my if structure:
if: expected a question and two answers, but found 4 parts

However  i am doing it according to the syntax.

```
 (if (or (null? list1) (null? list2))
    display(result-list)
    (begin
    (append result-list (list((car list1) list2)))
    (inner ((cdr list1) list2 result-list)))
     )
```

Could you please tell me where am i doing it wrong?

Comment: is `display(result-list)` exactly what you've written? it looks wrong

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The second line should be `(display result-list)`.

The way you wrote it, `display` is the then-part of the if, `(result-list)` is the else-part and the begin-block is the superfluous fourth part that your compiler/interpreter complains about.

Answer (score 1):

Shouldn't this `display(result-list)` be `(display result-list)`? Remember, `(call param1 param2)` is the scheme syntax, `call(param1 param2)` is C.